# Strange phase case in Bode diagram of a transfer function

Tags: control, theory

Please help me to solve my problem:
This is the transfer function: $G(s)=10\frac{(s^2+1)(s-10)}{s(s+0.1)(s^2+2s+100)}$

I calculated properly the whole Bode diagram apart from the phase of the complex zeros $(s^2+1)$. I would sum here at this point as usually: +180° and so does Wolfram's software in fact my result of the phase is equal to this one:

[image: Mine/Wolfram solution]

the problem is that my professor uses MATLAB which gives -180° and therefore this should be the right solution

[image: Professor/MATLAB solution]

I don't know which one is right and why, that's why I bother.

Comment: Maybe this question will be answered way faster if you post it in DSP or in EE: [DSP - Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=bode) [Electronics - Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Maria Bevieri, but I'm afraid that this doesn't look like a *Robotics* question. If you could edit your question to explain how your question relates to Robotics, we can re-open it for you. Alternatively, if you could let us know if this is [Electronics.se] or [DSP.se] related, then we can migrate your question to one of those sites. Please don't just ask the question again, it is better to migrate a question than post the same question on more than one site, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a phase unwrapping case in MATLAB. Anyway when real parts of complex poles/zeros are null, phase jump could be +180 or -180, it's uknown therefore both diagrams are correct